# Integrating action buttons in R shiny DT table

Tags: r, shiny, dt, shinybs

The given R shiny script creates a data table with some buttons, My requirement is to only keep the "CSV" button and based on onclick, use the bsmodal function from the shinyBS package to display the mtcars data in a popup.
Please help me in removing the other two buttons and creating a popup for the same. Thanks.

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)
ui <- basicPage(
h2("The mtcars data"),
DT::dataTableOutput("mytable"),
bsModal("modalExample", "Your Table", "csv", size = 
"large",dataTableOutput("irisTable")))
server <- function(input, output) {
output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
datatable(
  iris2,
  extensions = 'Buttons', options = list(
    dom = 'Bfrtip',
    buttons = c('csv')))})
output$irisTable = DT::renderDataTable({
datatable(
  mtcars)})
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: Dataset for shinyBS popup]

Comment: Read the documentation: https://datatables.net/reference/button/

Comment: @Victoria, that's what's my issue, these buttons seem to have their logic  written in the backend, please help me to tweak this by fitting my own logic.

Comment: `c('csv', 'print')` will give you two buttons. It looks like there is a minimum; But if you use the following code it will give you almost what you want. `extensions = 'Buttons', options = list(
        dom = 'Bfrtip',
        buttons = 
            list(list(
                extend = 'collection',
                buttons = c('csv'),
                text = 'csv'
            ))
        
    )`